# Can't send ACLMessage to remote agent

Tags: java, agents-jade

I use JADE to create an agent system. I have created two program: a server and a client.

*Server:*

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.instance(true);
Profile profile = new ProfileImpl();
jade.wrapper.AgentContainer agentcontainer =
    runtime.createMainContainer(profile);
agentcontainer.createNewAgent(
    "server", "MASServer.CenterAgent", new object[] { this }).start();
```

*Server's behaviour:*

```
ACLMessage AclAnswer = new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.INFORM);
AclAnswer.setContent("From server:helllo");
AID recei = new AID("client", AID.ISLOCALNAME);
AclAnswer.addReceiver(recei);
agent.send(AclAnswer);
```

*Client:*

```
Profile profile = new ProfileImpl(false);
profile.setParameter(ProfileImpl.MAIN_HOST, "myhostaddress");
Runtime runtime = Runtime.instance();
jade.wrapper.AgentContainer secondaryContainer =
     runtime.createAgentContainer(profile);
secondaryContainer.createNewAgent(
    "client", "MASClient.CenterAgent", new object[] { this }).start();
```

*Client's behaviour:*

```
ACLMessage AclAnswer = new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.INFORM);
AclAnswer.setContent("From client:helllo");
AID recei = new AID("server", AID.ISLOCALNAME);
AclAnswer.addReceiver(recei);
agent.send(AclAnswer);
```

When the server and the client programs run on the same computer, it works fine.

When the server runs on computer A and the client runs on computer B, the client can send an ACLMessage to the server, but the server can't send an ACLMessage to the client. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Is the server agent waiting for the client agent's container to join the platform before it sends the message? Your code shows that the server will send a message, but not **when** it will do so.

If the server sends the message as soon as it starts, it is not guaranteed that *client* has joined the platform. If there is no valid recipient, the message will then disappear and it won't be redelivered.

Answer (score 0):

Is not problem here?

```
new AID("server", AID.ISLOCALNAME);
```

If client and server are on different computers, shouldnt be used global unique name of the agent (`AID.ISGUID`) ?